# Is it possible to lock a drawing from overwrtting in c graphics

Tags: c

I am working on a c program in paint so i want to show the rough drawing during the drag-drop(for eg: while drawing a circle it shows the circle size increasing or decreasing till you release the mouse button). And for this i have run a loop while the click is on and it draws the respective figure and after the movement of the cursor i overwrite it with the same figure with the bgcolor so that the figure hides as soon as the mouse is moved and finally the release of click gives the original figure! But this gave me a bug that is if i draw another figure over it the clearing of the rough figure clears the previous figure as well! So is there a way to lock drawing on the previously constructed figure something sort of setviewport for a particular area as setviewport wont allow me to draw in an area rather than for a figure.

Comment: While dragging the objects (circle, rectangle or whatever) draw it using *xor*. No explicit clearing is needed then. Or keep a list of all objects, and if some is damaged then redraw it. Or keep a copy of the complete image, and instead of clearing just the object you are drawing just repaint (by blitting the copy) the whole background.

Comment: There is no thing like "C graphics". Graphics is far beyond standard C.